# Слитное написание сложных прилагательных

Tags: слитно-дефис

Почему слова древнерусский, церковнославянский, старославянский  пишутся слитно?

Comment: Внимательно читаю все Ваши вопросы и ответы. Только скоро никто отвечать не будет.Вам форумчане столько
плюсов наставили, а вам никакой ответ не нравится. Снобизм какой-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут слова, образованные от словосочетаний, в которых слова связаны подчинительной связью, если не ошибаюсь, а они пишутся слитно всегда.

Comment: Большинство  сложных прилагательных со слитной формой написания, действительно, образуются на основе сочетаний с подчинительной связью, поэтому этот признак чаще всего используется при решении  подобных задач. В частности, можно считать: Древняя Русь → древнерусский.  
Однако, в словах «церковнославянский и старославянский» связь основ не подчинительная, а СОЧИНИТЕЛЬНАЯ (неоднородное сочинение), для сравнения: всемирный исторический → всемирно-исторический, тем не менее слова пишутся слитно, а не через дефис.

Comment: Дело в том, что эти слова НЕ ЯВЛЯЮТСЯ СЛОЖЕНИЕМ  исходных прилагательных СТАРЫЙ И СЛАВЯНСКИЙ, ЦЕРКОВНЫЙ И СЛАВЯНСКИЙ, так как нет лингвистических терминов «старый  славянский язык, церковный славянский язык».

ДЛЯ СПРАВОК: СТАРОСЛАВЯНСКИЙ ЯЗЫК –   первый письменный славянский язык (по происхождению письменная обработка одного из говоров болгарского языка 9-10 вв);  ЦЕРКОВНОСЛАВЯНСКИЙ ЯЗЫК – одна из современных форм (изводов) старославянского языка, употребляемая в основном в православном богослужении.

Comment: В этом случае (при отсутствии подчинительной связи основ)  требуется решение более общего порядка:  слитно пишутся сложные прилагательные,  включающие две  (или более) основы и образованные одним из способов, характерным для сложных прилагательных: чистое сложение основ, суффиксальное сложение, сращение.  При решении нашей задачи используем ЧИСТОЕ СЛОЖЕНИЕ, в качестве опорного прилагательного используется слово СЛАВЯНСКИЙ, и к нему добавляется первая основа: старый, славянский →стар(о) славянский, церковный, славянский →церковн(о)славянский.